# Node.js from yum on Fedora fails to start with v8 symbol error

Tags: yum, downgrade, node.js, fedora-16, v8

I installed the nodejs package on Fedora 16 this way:

```
# yum install nodejs
```

But it crashed on startup when run with no arguments:

```
$ nodejs
nodejs: ../src/handle_wrap.cc:65: static v8::Handle<v8::Value> 
    node::HandleWrap::Unref(const v8::Arguments&): Assertion 
    `args.Holder()->InternalFieldCount() > 0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

And also with an empty file:

```
$ nodejs /dev/null
nodejs: symbol lookup error: nodejs: undefined symbol: 
    _ZN2v82V837AdjustAmountOfExternalAllocatedMemoryEi
```

How can I install Node.js on Fedora using yum and not have it crash when it starts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second error is a decent clue that the problem is not a code error in Node.js but a binary incompatibility problem between C++ components.  That symbol in C++ is `v8::V8::AdjustAmountOfExternalAllocatedMemory(int)`.  So let's try a different version of v8, like this:

```
# yum downgrade v8
```

On my Fedora 16 system this took v8 from 3.10 to 3.6.  And now nodejs works!

Answer (score 3):

Both answers given are not complete solutions: as soon as you execute `yum update` or `yum upgrade` v8 will be upgraded again. The complete solution is as followed:

First remove v8 and add the nodejs-stable repository to yum, just like ftrotter said:

```
$ sudo yum -y remove v8
$ sudo yum localinstall --nogpgcheck http://nodejs.tchol.org/repocfg/fedora/nodejs-stable-release.noarch.rpm
```

Now you should find out which repos provide v8:

```
$ yum info v8
```

On my system there were 2 repos providing v8: `updates` and `nodejs-stable`. We only want v8 from nodejs-stable, so we should exclude v8 from all the other repos. We can exclude a package using the repo config files. These files could be found in `/etc/yum.repos.d/`. The config file for the `updates` repo is `fedora-updates.repo`. Open that file and add `exclude=v8*` to the `[updates]` section of that file. Finally you can reinstall v8, node and npm:

```
$ sudo yum install npm
```

V8 won't be downloaded from the `updates` repository anymore, but only from the `nodejs-stable` repository. Therefore yum will always download the right v8 version for node.

Answer (score 3):

If you are getting the error stated above, stop, and do the following:

```
$ sudo yum -y remove v8
$ sudo yum localinstall --nogpgcheck http://nodejs.tchol.org/repocfg/fedora/nodejs-stable-release.noarch.rpm # You probably already have this repo installed, may be skipped.

# Next line will reinstall older version of V8 and working NPM -
$ sudo yum --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=nodejs-stable install nodejs-compat-symlinks npm
```

Comment: This answer looks to be the same as what ftrotter posted a while ago.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this problem on one system, while another system that should be identical didn't have the problem.

While investigating I noticed that `yum resolvedep v8` said `1:v8-3.13.7.5-1.el6.x86_64` on both systems, but `yum info v8` didn't show v8 as installed on the system that was working.

On a hunch I ran `yum remove v8` on the broken system, which removed `1:v8-3.13.7.5-1.el6.x86_64` *and* `nodejs-0.6.18-1.el6.x86_64`.

Then I did `yum install nodejs` which installed *only* `nodejs-0.6.18-1.el6.x86_64`, and now the nodejs works fine.

Comment: This worked for me on an Amazon EC2 CentOS instance.

Answer (score 0):

I think John is right about this problem, but his solution did not work for me.

I found the right answer for me [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nodejs/q506uBajYTQ%5B1-25%5D)

from that post:

The easiest way to fix it is to remove v8 and it's dependencies and reinstall them using only the nodejs-stable repository:

```
$ sudo yum -y remove v8
$ sudo yum localinstall --nogpgcheck http://nodejs.tchol.org/repocfg/fedora/nodejs-stable-release.noarch.rpm # You probably already have this repo installed
$ sudo yum --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=nodejs-stable install nodejs-compat-symlinks npm
```

Comment: Just like the other solution mentioned here this only works partially: when you run `yum upgrade` v8 is upgraded to a newer version again. Do you know if there's a way to force yum to update v8 only from the nodejs-stable repo?